# I am getting invalid interval between two datetime

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am getting invalid interval between two datetime

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$zurich = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata');
$datetimeFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$date->setTimestamp($request->travel_time);
$d1 = $date->format($datetimeFormat);
$date2 = new \DateTime();
$d2 = $alreadyCreatedRoute[0]->travel_time;
$datetime1 = new DateTime($d2,$zurich);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($d1,$zurich);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
 `echo $diff_in_minutes = $interval->format('%h')." Hours ".$interval->format('%i')." Minutes";`
**DateTime Object([date] => 2018-02-12 10:19:11.000000 [timezone_type] =>3
    [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata**
)
**DateTime Object([date] => 2018-02-12 00:11:00.000000 [timezone_type] =>3
    [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata)**
```

Comment: Please update your question to include a proper and clear example of your input data, expected output and your current output.

Comment: Just to many datetime operations. What do you have in `$request->travel_time` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you exactly want but if its date difference then here is the code to find the difference between 2 DateTime

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Comment: thank you @nikita but I am getting wrong difference

`DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2018-02-12 10:19:11.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
)


DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2018-02-12 00:11:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
)`